# Fusion Chart Hide Number Prefix for One Bar

Tags: charts, fusioncharts

I need to remove the dollar ($) sign from the top of the first bar which is showing the values $410K,only we need 410K.
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/TumnU/1489/)

`"chart": {
        "caption": "Daily Revenue by Order",
        "subcaption": "Last 2 weeks",
        "xaxisname": "Date",
        "yaxisname": "Revenue (In USD)",
        "numberprefix": "$",
        "showvalues": "1",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "data": [{
          "label": "Total Order",
          "value": "410000"
        },`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to remove **numberPrefix** attribute. Using this attribute, you could add the prefix to all the numbers visible on the graph.

Hence the modified code will be following.

```
"chart": {
    "caption": "Daily Revenue by Order",
    "subcaption": "Last 2 weeks",
    "xaxisname": "Date",
    "yaxisname": "Revenue (In USD)",
    "showvalues": "1",
    "theme": "fusion"
  },
  "data": [{
      "label": "Total Order",
      "value": "410000"
    },
```